# Gradle play-services-measurement-base issue

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an issue when I trying to use Firebase Dynamic Links. The problem arises only when I add that library to dependencies but everything works properly if I remove it:

```
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is
being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0],
[15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check
your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

I've looked everywhere, on different stackoverflow questions with the same problem but couldn't find any viable solution. It either gives me the error above or doesn't compile (same module used twice or similar). I've also tried to upgrade to the latest versions but no luck.

My dependencies:

```
def support_library_version = '27.0.2'
def firebase_and_play_services_version = '15.0.0'
def firebase_version = '15.0.0'
def retrofitVersion = '2.4.0'
def jacksonVersion = '2.9.2'
def daggerVersion = '2.16'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    implementation group: 'com.gimbal.android.v3', name: 'gimbal-sdk', version: '3.2.1'
    implementation group: 'com.gimbal.android.v3', name: 'gimbal-slf4j-impl', version: '3.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0'

    implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$support_library_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_library_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$firebase_and_play_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$firebase_and_play_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$firebase_and_play_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$firebase_and_play_services_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$firebase_and_play_services_version"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebase_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:$firebase_version"

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0"

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation('com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.5') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion"

    //--- RxJava ---//
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'
    implementation 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    kapt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.4.0'
    implementation 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.4.0'

    implementation 'com.pacioianu.david:ink-page-indicator:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:process-phoenix:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I've also updated root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: With the new Google Play and Firebase versioning scheme you should [migrate away from using common version numbers](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#remove_old_anti-pattern).

Comment: I had a [strange problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025793/4815718) that was resolved by putting `firebase-core` before all other Google Play and Firebase libs.  You might try that.

Comment: Also safer to put `google()` before `jcenter()` in the repo list.  See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253780/4815718

Comment: Nope, none of the above works unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error in a test build using support library version 27.1.1 and only the Google Play and Firebase libs shown below.  Updating to the latest versions of those (as shown) resolved the problem.  I don't know if this creates conflicts with the other libs you use.

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.0.1"
```

Comment: Man, you made my day! BIG Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your firebase dependencies to newest version, check them from [Firebase site](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

> If your app has a dependency on
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0 as well as any of the
>   following libraries:
>
> ```
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager
> com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crash
> com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links
> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging
> ```
>
> You will need to update the version of the latter dependency to
>   15.0.2. This addresses the issue where version 3.3.0 of the Google Services Gradle plugin reports: The library
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0],
>   [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2...

From [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: Done that already. It does not work. I've tried with making everything `15.0.2` and again, it doesn't work. I get error like this: `Unable to resolve dependency for ':App@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.2.
Open File
Show Details`

Comment: there is no play-services-gcm:15.0.2, only 15.0.1, you don't need to update play-services version, just firebase ones

Comment: I've downgraded gcm to `15.0.0`, upgraded firebase to latest `16.0.0` or `16.0.1` and I'm back to the beginning. Same issue: `The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: well, it seems you will have to update play-services to, but the problem for you is that play-services-gcm is removed, see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm